# onNotificationPosted() method not called when the app is running in background

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have written an app that reads notifications arriving to android device (API>=19) and used **onNotificationPosted()** method part of NotificationListenerService. I am able to read the posted notifications only if I keep the app active on the screen. Is there anyway I can keep the app **running in the background** and still use onNotificationsPosted method to retrieve the notification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let your Service's onStartCommand return START_STICKY flag

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

I am already using NotificationServiceListener which by default runs in the background. The mistake was with the broadcast receiver. I have unregistered the broadcast on pause which is the reason the app couldn't fetch notifications when running in background. Just unregistering it in onDestroy works. One other interesting way to retain the sent broadcast even if the app is killed is by using stickybroadcasts.